# Solving system upper triangular linear system of ODEs - solving ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have the system [image]

Then, $y'=Ay \rightarrow y=PUP^{-1}(y) \rightarrow P^{-1}(y)=UP^{-1}(y)$. Then let $z=P^{-1}(y) \rightarrow z'=Uz$.

I am trying to figure out how to solve this system now. I have:

$z_n'=u_{nn}z_n \rightarrow z_n(t)=z_n(0)e^{u_{nn}t}$

$z_{n-1}'=u_{n-1,n-1}z_{n-1}+u_{n-1,n}z_n \rightarrow z_{n-1}'=u_{n-1,n-1}z_{n-1}+u_{n-1,n}z_n(0)e^{u_{nn}t}$,

but I am having trouble solving for $z_{n-1}$.

Comment: Integrating factor?

Comment: Thank you! You were right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [solutions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_differential_equation) of $y' = A y$ are
$$
y(t) = \exp(tA)\, y(0) \, .
$$
All we need is to compute the [matrix exponential](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_exponential) $\exp(tA)$. If $A$ is not only similar to the triangular matrix $U$ but also to a diagonal matrix $D$, then this computation is straightforward.